# Stop Google From Indexing Search Queries

Tags: duplicates, google-search

I am getting flagged for duplicate title tags on pages with user generated searches using the installed Google Search bar on our site.

Ex.
    www.website.com/search/
    www.website.com/search/?=searchterm1
    www.website.com/search/?=searchterm2

1.) What is the best process to block these from being indexed?
2.) Will this affect my Google Search on my site?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: There is no code to post, my report from SEM rush is showing duplicate tags for pages which are appended, website.com/search?=searchterm-1 these are automatically generated pages based on the search query when a user enters a term into my google search box on my site.